# WCF webservice is not returning the correct status code when the response header is modified

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, web-services

I have a very simple WCF web service which I call on the client side using Ajax:

Here is my web service:

```
public string TestService() {
    throw new Exception();
    return "";
}
```

Here is what my client side Ajax call looks like:

```
var mySuccess = function(result,statuscode,xhr){
    alert('success');
}

var myFail = function(result,statuscode,xhr){
    alert('failure');
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'Post'
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: '../myService.svc/TestService',
    data: '',
    dataType: "json",
    success: mySuccess,
    error: myFail
});
```

This web service fails every time (as it should!), returning a status and code of '500: internal server error'.  The 'myFail' callback function is fired as it should.

However, if I modify the response header within my web service, like so:

```
public string TestService() {
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("token", "1");
    throw new Exception();
    return "";
}
```

then the status/code returned is '200: OK', every time!

This means that the 'mySuccess' function is fired every time, even when the web service should be failing. I can't figure out why simply adding my own custom header to the response would overwrite the return status in this way.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: I am able to reproduce the behavior. Looks like a bug.

Comment: Thats awkward then. Is there any other way to pass some reponse back to the client - which doesn't involve fiddling with the actual return value?

Comment: I don't think so. All that the client sees is the actual HTTP response which contains 2 parts: the response headers and the body.

Comment: Personally I think has more to do with the fact that you [Cannot modify header information](http://docs.joomla.org/Cannot_modify_header_information_-_headers_already_sent) after they've been set.  In regular ASP.NET you would just buffer the response.

Comment: I've decided to send the modified header information, accepting that I'll lose any error codes returned. Server exceptions are always returning a well defined JSON exception string, which I can parse to see if the service call failed.

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to throw a `WebFaultException` with a meaningful HTTP status and message.
Example:  `throw new WebFaultException("Invalid request received.", HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);`
BadReuqest code is 400.